# Ubuntu won't find enough space to download itself

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hibernate

So I've been looking around all the internet, tried a lot of things, but still, this problem won't get fixed. 
I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Lenovo Yoga 730, alongside Windows.

The Ubuntu ISO is on the USB inserted to PC. All goes nice until the part where I select language and click next, then I get this message: ''***You need at least 8.6 GB to install Ubuntu. This computer has only 4.1 GB***''

So my computer actually has 300 GB+ available. I've turned of Hibernation.
I have also done the 'Shrink volume' on disk management.

Also, when I run on 'try mode', I wrote this on terminal and get:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo parted -l
Model: Generic Flash Disk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 4090MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4090MB  4089MB  primary  fat32        boot, lba
```

Help is highly appreciated!

Comment: after you shrank your windows drive, did you format the blank space?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED-------

I did switch Windows 10 from IDE to AHCI operation. That solved the problem.
This are the steps:

1) Open CMD as admin. type `bcdedit /set safeboot minimal`

2) Restart computer and enter BIOS setup

3) Change SATA to AHCI

4) Save and exit

5) Open CMD as admin again and type `bcdedit /deletevalue safeboot`

And then the problem is resolved.